# How to fix my ASP.NET Webforms structure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, webforms

I have a problem with the structure of an old asp.net webform page. Now i want to convert this into an MVC page, because i think there a several things which does MVC automatically...

**Here are the facts about the software:**

1. The software is not a "real" asp.net project, just a collaction of many aspx pages which are called with ajax (single pages for every event).

   - One page for "ModuleOne/save/"
   - One page for "ModuleOne/edit/"
   - One page for "ModuleOne/create/" and so on... I think you know what i want to tell you...
2. The software use two different languages (vb.net, c#) inside the app_code directory with two subdirectories (vbcode, csharpcode)
3. The software use the "yui compress plugin (js/css)", which is good but there are a lot of better plugins in mvc (do it automatically with bundles...)
4. The global.asax has a lot of routes to the aspx pages

**Now, i want to fix theses problems with the following points:**

1. Convert the collaction of asp.net pages to a "real" asp.net web app project
2. Convert the vb.net classes to one dll file and add a new reference on it
3. Eleminate the "yui compress plugin" and replace it with the functionality in mvc (bundles)
4. Eliminate the "manual routes" in the global.asax an replace this with the "controller handling" in mvc.

In my opinion mvc is the best solution to fix all theses "project-structure-problems"?!

What do you think about this solution/new structure? Make this sense?

Comment: yes, everything about your situation screams MVC. The controllers can serve up your aspx files. But beware: do you use any "server side" controls? and user controls? Ajax update panels? none of those is supported in asp.net mvc...

Comment: i don't have any server-side controls or ajax update panel in den "old" software... so i think the only way to fix these problem is to convert it to an mvc application...

Comment: I suspect the best way to do that would be to create MVC project and `add` each aspx page as a view in views folder for each controller thru solution explorer.